# Checking new row is inserted in table database and run some script

Tags: android, sql, database

I want to send some notification to android app when new row is inserted in table database, but I'm having trouble to check if there is new row inserted or not.

Is there any function or query to check if new row inserted in table? or some logic to acquire that.

Comment: You can use a trigger.

Comment: yes, but I can't do that because its not my database and I don't have permission to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the database you are using.
For example in MySQL you can query the table information_schema.tables to get the latest update time.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html

**For postgres**

Check if track commit timestamp is on

```
show track_commit_timestamp;
```

If it's off, set it to on in your postgresql.conf file and restart postgres.

Post that run the following to track the latest updates in your table

```
SELECT pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin), * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: how about postgresql ?, did postgresql have table that store some information

Comment: What version of postgres are you using?

Comment: I use postgresql 12

Comment: Use this : SELECT pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin), * FROM  YOUR_TABLE_NAME;

Comment: I will try this method